# Offtopic: Where to purchase

Tags: discussion

Should we consider adding a reason of "where to purchase" or something similar to the off topic list for questions asking where they can buy a game? Also would some types of this question be valid?

- Where to purchase physical copy
- Where to purchase digital copy (print and play)
- Where to purchase computer version (physical copy)
- Where to purchase computer version (digital copy)

Personally I would lean towards them being off topic but I am not sure if they warrant a close reason (either from lack of these questions or just in general).

I am asking in response to a question about purchasing a print and play copy that appears to be a kickstarter exclusive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shopping questions are generally frowned upon if not off-topic by consensus across the network. The only sites that explicitly allow them are specifically for shopping questions, and have a very tight list of criteria to ensure high quality, and still are closing a lot of the questions they get.

The questions are too broad to be reasonably answered for a majority of users, and answers are going to be outdated fairly rapidly or inapplicable for most users.

They should be treated no differently from recommendations, and in fact this is a superset of that existing close reason, which should be changed to read

> I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because... shopping questions are off-topic on Board & Card Games SE. This includes questions asking for game or supplier recommendations.

Comment: I know they are generally off-topic but there are some sites with exceptions so I wanted to verify what people thought here.